# Mismatch between mobile app and mobile site reputation history

Tags: bug, ios-app, reputation-history

Today, my reputation gained from yesterday started showing up different on the iOS app. The amount of reputation gained is different from the full mobile site and the mobile app for some reason:

[image]

Mobile app shows +150 although just 12 hours earlier it said +200:

[image]

And this is mismatched between the site and the app:

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.1.1 (Build 14B100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with achievements.

When the web site presents achievements, it takes 250 reputation events, combines reputation events for the same action, merges that with the last 50 achievements (badges), and shows the 50 most recent events.

The mobile app does something similar, but in a different order.  The API merges the 50 most recent reputation events and 50 most recent achievements and returns the 50 most recent.  The app the combines reputation events for the same actions.

This can cause a huge disparity between the two interfaces.  Added to that, the API only returns reputation events for posts, so documentation reputation doesn't appear at all.

We're currently planning on directly consuming the topbar models in the app, but there's no firm timeline for this feature.